# How do I configure iptables to allow Jetpack and update checking on WordPress to go out from my server?

Tags: iptables, https

I am running Centos 7 and Nginx for a WordPress server. Jetpack complains that it can't reach WordPress because outbound HTTPS is blocked.

My website runs over HTTPS.

Core and plugin updates can't be checked because it complains:

> Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with
>   WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have
>   problems, please try the support forums. (**WordPress could not
>   establish a secure connection to WordPress.org**. Please contact your
>   server administrator.) in
>   /var/www/example.com/html/wp-includes/update.php on line 320

I've got the following in iptables:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Feb 13 14:20:10 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3:160]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [8:568]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8:568]
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination [SNIPPED]:443
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Feb 13 14:20:10 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Feb 13 14:20:10 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [42790:10270531]
# Cloudflare
-A INPUT -s 199.27.128.0/21 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 198.41.128.0/17 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 197.234.240.0/22 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 190.93.240.0/20 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 188.114.96.0/20 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 173.245.48.0/20 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 172.64.0.0/13 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 162.158.0.0/15 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 141.101.64.0/18 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 131.0.72.0/22 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 108.162.192.0/18 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 104.16.0.0/12 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 103.31.4.0/22 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 103.22.200.0/22 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 103.21.244.0/22 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
# End Cloudflare    
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10101:10111 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Feb 13 14:20:10 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Feb 13 14:20:10 2017
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [41531:17444520]
:INPUT ACCEPT [41531:17444520]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [42790:10270531]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [42790:10270531]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Feb 13 14:20:10 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Feb 13 14:20:10 2017
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [41531:17444520]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [42790:10270531]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Feb 13 14:20:10 2017
```

Applied and restarted, but still no luck.

Looking at the code in update.php line 320 and it appears to be trying to reach this url:

```
http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/update-check/1.1/
```

I can hit that url using curl from my server, but from what I can see the code is making a call to a HTTP API, but I can't see how or what else is going on. I don't think this is  a WordPress issue per se, it feels like something to do with outbound HTTPS from the server, or certificates perhaps.

I can't see anything of interest in system logs (I can't start auditd on my VM), but digging around in logs for the site I see this:

> *1648 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.158.154.184, server:
>   example.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:",
>   host: "www.example.com", referrer:
>   "https://www.example.com/wp-admin/plugin-install.php"

Another interesting error is:

> Installation failed: Download failed. cURL error 51: Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.

Comment: I have also removed Cloudflare from the equation entirely.

Comment: What is the purpose of the outbound dnat rule?

Comment: @Aaron This is where I admit I was following a tutorial for setting up, and now can't remember what tutorial it was nor what the purpose of the rule was. Obviously wrong to be there as taking it out fixed the problem and broke nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

In iptables, this was doing it:

```
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination [SNIPPED]:443
```

Removing this rule solved the problem.